# Вызов operator[] через operator[] const

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class Integer
{
public:
    const int& operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        std::cout << "const int& Integer::operator[](unsigned int) const"
            << std::endl;

        return p[i];
        // return const_cast<Integer&>(*this)[i];
    }
    int& operator[](size_t i)
    {
        std::cout << "int& Integer::operator[](unsigned int)"
            << std::endl;

        return const_cast<int&>(static_cast<const Integer&>(*this)[i] );
        // return p[i];
    }

private:
    int* p;
};
```

Почему лучше вызывать константный operator[] из не константного operator[] а не наоборот. Я не вижу разницы между этими двумя способами. Ведь константность снимается для временного объекта и только для того что бы вызвать перегруженную функцию.

Comment: Потому что вот за такое - превращение константы в неконстанту - маленьким программистам массируют копчик. Это можно делать только в самом крайнем случае, когда у вас нет абсолютно никакого доступа к коду, который писал какой-то чайник, не умеющий работать с `const`. Никогда, *никогда*, **никогда** без крайней нужды не превращайте константную сущность в неконстантную!!!

Comment: используя пример из вопроса, можешь показать реальный пример не хороших последствий.

Comment: Маерс в книжке Эффективное использование с++ детально отвечает на этот вопрос в 3 совете.

Comment: отвечает но не детально.

Comment: А у Мейерса в книге лишний квалификатор const у неконстантной ф-ии-члена стоит, да? Или это только в электронном издании?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С самого начала отмечу, что отбрасывать константность нехорошо. Но дублирование кода - тоже плохо. Поэтому в случае вызова неконстантной функции-члена мы отбрасываем константность, т.к. и ожидается объект неконстантный. А если вызываем константный оператор - то нужно гарантировать, что если в нем вызывается другой оператор то он ничего не поменяет, а если этот оператор неконстантный, значит он может что-то поменять, поэтому и гарантий мы таких дать не можем. Следовательно, так вызывать не стоит, это небезопасно.

Как пишет *Скотт Мейерс* в своей книге «*Эффективное использование C++*»:

> Решать эту задачу наоборот - путем вызова неконстантной версии из
>   константной - неправильно. Помните, что константная функция-член
>   обещает никогда не изменять логическое состояние объекта, а не­
>   константная не дает таких гарантий. Если вы вызовете неконстантную
>   функцию из константной, то рискуете получить ситуацию, когда объект,
>   который не дол­жен модифицироваться, будет изменен. Вот почему этого
>   не следует делать: что­бы объект не изменился. Фактически, чтобы
>   получить компилируемый код, вам пришлось бы использовать `const_cast`
>   для отбрасывания константности `*this`, а это явный признак неудачного
>   решения. Обратная последовательность вызовов - безопасна. Неконстантная > функция-член может де­лать все, что захочет с объектом, поэтому вызов из > нее константной функции­ члена ничем не грозит. Потому-то мы и применяем > к `*this` оператор `static_cast`, отбрасывания константности при этом нет.

Comment: мне не хватило такого ответа Мейерса, сюда пришел я от него

Comment: @StanislavPetrov А чего конкретно Вам не хватило? В одном случае у Вас есть гарантии неизменяемости, в другом - нет.

Comment: почему в другом нет гарантий

Comment: Если вы вызовете неконстантную функцию из константной, то рискуете получить ситуацию, когда объект, который не дол­жен модифицироваться, будет изменен. - вот эту ситуацию как симетировать.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Потому что неконстантная функция-член может изменить объект. В примере не показана такая ситуация, но такая реализация возможна, никаких запретов нет.

Comment: грубо говоря, в коде вопроса нет ничего опасного? если считать что код не будет дополняться и расширяться?

Comment: @StanislavPetrov все хорошо в коде вопроса.

Comment: я имел ввиду закомментированный вариант.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov ну если не будет расширяться, то нормально, можно и так вызвать. Только там в первом случае в возвращаемый тип надо константность добавить. Поменять местами static и const касты, взятые из второго варианта.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Гарантий нет, потому что эти гарантии даете вы лично (кто ж вам поверит-то!), а **не компилятор**.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov В коде вопроса (в обоих вариантах) все плохо, так они оба содержат немотивированное использование `const_cast`.